# Old scanner compatibility with Yosemite?

Tags: macos, compatibility, scanning

I have an old scanner a UMAX Astra 6400 which I can't get my newly upgraded Yosemite system to register. I'm using the FireWire 400 interface and the scanner is powering on correctly.

I think it might be TWAIN compliant and I'm aware support was dropped for TWAIN back on 10.5.

I have also tried installing this TWAIN Bridge package to see if it would work, but still no luck.

Also tried [VueScan](http://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/umax_astra_6400.html) which is apparently compatible too but I get the following error.

[image]

Any ideas on how I can get this scanner working with my Yosemite system?

Comment: This site claims to have the driver for your scanner. http://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/umax_astra_6400.html

Comment: Try using Apple Image Capture app in your Application folder.

Comment: Tried Image Capture, also Mac's don't need drivers.

Comment: Hamrick Software is very responsive, and Vuescan is usually the only way to get old scanners to work, since manufacturers don't update the drivers.  Send them an email: they will almost certainly work with you to get it working, and I'd bet they'll do that before you purchase the software so you know it'll work for you.

Comment: In my experience, VueScan only support USB-connected scanners. It would not recognize my scanner (CanoScan 9950F) until I switched from Firewire to USB.